How can I reconstruct a normal distribution from a set of percentiles?
I have the 3rd, 10th, 50th, 90th, and 97th percentile values of a normally distributed variable, and I wish to generate a dataset that will allow me to query for other percentile values (say, the 67th.)
I (naively, I'm sure) tried the following, and it failed:
underlying_data = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=[1000])

percentiles = np.percentile(underlying_data, [3, 10, 50, 90, 97])

#

generated_data = []

for i in range(3):
    generated_data.append(underlying_data[0])

for i in range(7):
    generated_data.append(underlying_data[1])

for i in range(80):
    generated_data.append(underlying_data[2])

for i in range(7):
    generated_data.append(underlying_data[3])

for i in range(3):
    generated_data.append(underlying_data[4])

print("from underlying distribution: ", np.percentile(np.array(underlying_data), [67]))
print("from generated distribution: ", np.percentile(np.array(generated_data), [67]))

Outputting:
from underlying distribution:  [0.44470627]
from generated distribution:  [-0.73888881]


See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365865/build-a-normal-distribution-from-n-quartiles-and-mean

Do you have the sample size as well?

The underlying sample size is large, say a couple of million.

I'd recommend an approach as detailled here, also mentioned in Stephan's answer.

With a couple of million data points, it might be feasible and even faster to calculate the mean and the standard deviation directly, rather than first calculate five quantiles (likely sorting the values in the process).

That's a reasonable point Stephan, thank you, but in this instance I don't have access to the underlying data, I've just been given these five percentile values.

There are some previous questions that relate to this.

You could do reasonably well by treating the large-sample quantiles as themselves approximately multivariate normal with means and variances related to the parameters of interest a given correlation structure.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34882

I am not quite sure why you think your code should give you the results you are looking for.
The simplest approach would be to note that the median of the normal distribution is equal to the mean, so you could use your 50% quantile as an estimate $\hat{\mu}$. Next, for a normal distribution the 10% quantile is 1.28 times the standard deviation away from the mean, so you could estimate
$$ \hat{\sigma} := \frac{\hat{\mu}-q_{0.10}}{1.28}. $$
For slightly higher stability, you could estimate $\sigma$ in the same way using the 90% quantile, and take the average of the two estimates.
Note that this is very crude, and leverages only a few of your data points. But it has the advantage of being extremely simple to understand.
The "right" way to do this would be to numerically optimize both estimates, with an objective function that minimizes the difference between the quantiles of the fitted distribution and the quantiles you feed in. This will be more accurate. It will also be more complicated, more error-prone, and much slower.

I think your final paragraph is a bit pessimistic about the extra complication & reduced speed of a more sophisticated solution. Solving an overdetermined system by OLS isn't that much slower than taking a subset of those equations and solving them exactly. And that's a good jumping-off point for another level of improvement with low computational cost: applying weights to the equations to represent the fact the median has a lower sampling variance, hence is more trustworthy, than the extreme percentiles in the tails. I got pretty good results

@Silverfish: I absolutely agree and was your first upvote. That said, considering the approach that OP started with, I am a tiny little bit unsure how comfortable they are with OLS, even if it is bread and butter to statisticians.

A very fair point - simple is often better! I don't think they'd get terrible results by averaging out a few results from different pairs of equations. If the OP is stats-phobic but happy coding arrays and matrices, then the OLS approach boils down to solving
$\mathbf{X}\hat\beta=y$, where $\hat\beta$ is a vector containing the mean and SD estimates, $y$ is the vector of observed percentiles and $\mathbf X$ is a matrix with column of ones and then a column of the appropriate z-scores. The solution is $\hat \beta = (\mathbf{X}^t\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^ty$

If the percentiles are fixed then the OP could pre-compute $(\mathbf{X}^t\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^t$, which basically gives a matrix of coefficients to use for calculating the estimated $\hat \mu$ and $\hat \sigma$ as linear combinations of the observed percentiles. That rather hides the "statty" details of what's going on, but would be very easy for a programmer to code.

You have a system of equations, all of the form $\mu + z_i \sigma \approx q_i$ where $q_i$ is one of your percentiles (or more generally, quantiles), and $z_i$ is the corresponding z-score. So $z \approx 1.96$ if you take the 97.5th percentile, for example. The equations only hold approximately rather than exactly due to sampling error. If we include an error term then we could write exact equations
$$\mu + \sigma z_i  + \varepsilon_i = q_i$$
which look suspiciously like the regression equation for a line of best fit...
Your system is overdetermined because you have five equations to estimate only two parameters. You could pick two equations and solve them simultaneously as Stephan Kolassa suggests. You almost certainly can't solve all five simultaneously because sampling variation means the parameter estimates in the five equations are not going to be consistent with each other. But you could take the "least squares" approach, trying to minimise the sum of squared errors across your five equations. This is simpler than it sounds: as the hint above suggests we just need to regress the quantiles against their z-scores. The intercept will be your estimated mean, and the slope your estimated standard deviation.
Here's R code for a function using your percentiles as defaults:
estimate_params <- function(
    percentiles,
    cum_probs = c(0.03, 0.10, 0.50, 0.90, 0.97)) {
  z_scores <- qnorm(cum_probs)
  model <- lm(percentiles ~ z_scores)
  params <- coefficients(model)
  names(params) <- c("mu", "sigma")
  params
}

Does this work? Let's simulate 10,000 data points with mean 42 and standard deviation 10.
set.seed(100)
true_mu <- 42
true_sigma <- 10
N <- 1e4
cum_probs <- c(0.03, 0.10, 0.50, 0.90, 0.97)

underlying_data <- rnorm(N, mean = true_mu, sd = true_sigma)
quantiles <- quantile(underlying_data, probs = cum_probs)
print(quantiles)
#>        3%      10%      50%      90%      97% 
#>  23.08953 29.56984 42.02545 54.68026 60.71053 

estimate_params(quantiles)
#>         mu     sigma 
#>  42.015122  9.936526

Not bad! Maybe it feels overkill to use regression to solve what looked like a simple algebraic problem, but the regression routine in your software will be heavily optimised so it's not a lot of work computationally. Still, if the are always taking the 3rd, 10th, 50th, 90th and 97th percentiles, then there's no need to run a fresh regression analysis each time. In least-squares regression, the parameter estimates are just a linear combination of the observed values, and in your case we could just precompute the required coefficients. Then every time you get your observed quantiles, just multiply them by these coefficients and sum the products up, to get your estimate $\hat \mu$ for the mean or $\hat \sigma$ for the SD. Even less computational work! Let's look at your equations again, in matrix form, assuming you are given $n$ quantiles.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & z_1 \\ 1 & z_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & z_n \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \hat \mu \\ \hat \sigma \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} q_1 \\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ q_n \end{bmatrix} $$
The matrix on the left is called the design matrix, commonly denoted $\mathbf X$. Denote the vector of observed quantiles as $\mathbf q$. The least-squares solution for the estimated parameters is $(\mathbf{X}^t\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^t \mathbf{q}$. But if your percentiles are fixed, then the only part of this that varies from sample to sample is the observed quantiles $\mathbf{q}$ and we can precompute the matrix $(\mathbf{X}^t\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^t$ that multiplies them. We continue the previous R script.
precompute_coefficients <- function(cum_probs) {
  n <- length(cum_probs)
  z_scores <- qnorm(cum_probs)
  X <- matrix(c(rep(1, n), z_scores), ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
  coefs <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)
  rownames(coefs) <- c("mu", "sigma")
  colnames(coefs) <- names(quantile(0, cum_probs))
  coefs
}

our_coefs <- precompute_coefficients(cum_probs = cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(our_coefs, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>       3%            10%           50%          90%          97%         
#> mu    "0.20000000"  "0.20000000"  "0.20000000" "0.20000000" "0.20000000"
#> sigma "-0.18155223" "-0.12370764" "0.00000000" "0.12370764" "0.18155223"

# check matrix multiplication gives same result as regression
our_coefs %*% quantiles
#>            [,1]
#> mu    42.015122
#> sigma  9.936526

So with your percentiles, you can easily calculate the (ordinary) least-squares estimates of mean and SD by:
\begin{align}
\hat \mu &= \frac{q_{0.03} + q_{0.1} + q_{0.5} + q_{0.9} + q_{0.97}}{5} \\
\hat \sigma &= 0.18155223(q_{0.97} - q_{0.03}) + 0.12370764(q_{0.9} - q_{0.1})
\end{align}

In fact some of your percentiles are more informative than others, so treating them all the same way is not the best choice. The issue is that some sample percentiles have a lower variance than others — in other words they consistently tend to come out slightly closer to the true (population) percentile than the ones with high variance. We should give these estimates more importance in our calculation, which we could do by applying weighted least squares in our regression.
The variances you need come from the asymptotic distribution of the $p_i$-th sample quantile of a continuous random variable ("asymptotic" means this distribution is approximate, but is more accurate in large samples):
$$\text{Sample quantile } p_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(x_i, \frac{p_i(1-p_i)}{Nf(x_i)^2} \right)$$
where the sample size is $N$, the cumulative distribution function is $F(x)$, the probability density function is $f(x) = F'(x)$, and the corresponding population quantile is $x_i = F^{-1}(p_i)$.
Write $\Phi$ and $\phi$ for the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution.
Now consider when the underlying distribution is itself normal and let  $z_i = \Phi^{-1}(p_i)$ be the corresponding z-score to our quantile. Looking at the PDF curves, the normal distribution $f$ must be a factor of $\sigma$ wider than the standard normal distribution $\phi$, so can only be $1/\sigma$ times the height (to ensure both curves enclose an area of one). Hence $f(x_i) = \phi(z_i) / \sigma$ and our asymptotic distribution is:
$$\text{Sample quantile } p_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu + z_i \sigma, \frac{\sigma^2 p_i(1-p_i)}{N\phi(z_i)^2} \right)$$
which unfortunately features the unknown $\sigma$ in the numerator of our sampling variance. The good news is that this unknown factor $\sigma^2$ is the same for all our quantiles.
Let's see how much difference this makes in practice by taking 100,000 samples from our previous underlying distribution, and checking how much variation there is in our observed percentiles.
set.seed(100)
n_samples <- 1e5 # reduce this if on a slower machine!!
true_mu <- 42
true_sigma <- 10
N <- 1e4
cum_probs <- c(0.03, 0.10, 0.50, 0.90, 0.97)
z_scores <- qnorm(cum_probs)

generate_quantiles <- function() {
  underlying_data <- rnorm(N, mean = true_mu,
                           sd = true_sigma)
  quantile(underlying_data, probs = cum_probs)
}

repeated_quantiles <- replicate(n_samples, generate_quantiles())
colnames(repeated_quantiles) <- paste0("sample ", seq_len(n_samples))

print(repeated_quantiles[, 1:8])
#>     sample 1 sample 2 sample 3 sample 4 sample 5 sample 6 sample 7 sample 8
#> 3%  23.08953 23.04794 23.07882 23.44405 23.41065 22.73976 23.06871 23.44198
#> 10% 29.56984 29.08846 29.00956 29.32837 29.45000 29.15969 28.90494 29.40374
#> 50% 42.02545 41.97033 41.86143 41.83007 41.99313 41.95614 41.81269 42.17988
#> 90% 54.68026 54.51736 54.97305 54.84518 55.07962 54.67819 54.72953 55.17290
#> 97% 60.71053 60.72449 60.75950 60.42161 61.04273 60.54929 60.50323 60.87246

observed_quantile_vars <- apply(repeated_quantiles, 1, var)
theoretical_quantile_vars <- true_sigma^2 * cum_probs * (1-cum_probs) /
                             (N * dnorm(z_scores)^2)
names(theoretical_quantile_vars) <- names(observed_quantile_vars)

print(observed_quantile_vars)
#> 3%        10%        50%        90%        97% 
#> 0.06255275 0.02904089 0.01567281 0.02941661 0.06268904

print(theoretical_quantile_vars)
#>         3%        10%        50%        90%        97% 
#> 0.06285495 0.02922110 0.01570796 0.02922110 0.06285495

So exactly as our formula suggests, we should be putting more trust in the sample median because it has considerably less sampling variability than the more extreme percentiles. As is often the way, our sample gives us a better idea what the middle of our distribution looks like, while the picture in the tails is less clear.
If our observations were independent, we would apply weights that are proportional to the reciprocals of these sampling variances. Proportionality means we can forget about the unknown $\sigma^2$, fortunately, and also ignore the factor of $N$. Life is a little more complicated for us because sample quantiles are clearly correlated: if the 50th percentile is large, we expect the 51st percentile to be large too, and it certainly cannot be lower than the 50th. So our weights should be based on the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix instead of the reciprocals of the variances. (Note that weighting by the reciprocals of the variances is just a special case of inverting the variance-covariance matrix: if observations are independent, then the covariances on the off-diagonal cells of the matrix will be zero, and we take the inverse of such a diagonal matrix simply by reciprocating the diagonal entries.)
Note that you don't have to use a theoretical formula for the variance-covariance matrix: if you'll accept a slightly imperfect result, you could just estimate it by repeated sampling, similarly to how the code above estimates the variances before comparing them to the theoretical ones. But fortunately the theory isn't too hard. These lecture slides from David Stephens show the joint distribution of the sample quantiles is asymptotically multivariate normal. If we have two sample quantiles $q_i$ and $q_j$ corresponding to cumulative probabilities $p_i \le p_j$ and population quantiles $x_i$ and $x_j$, then their covariance is
$$\operatorname{Cov}(q_i, q_j) = \frac{p_i (1 - p_j)}{N f(x_i) f(x_j)} $$
which when the underlying distribution is normal becomes
$$\operatorname{Cov}(q_i, q_j) = \frac{\sigma^2 p_i (1 - p_j)}{N \phi(z_i) \phi(z_j)} $$
so we again obtain the factor $\sigma^2/N$.
The following R script is a continuation of the previous one. Let's check how big these covariances are (and that our formula is correct!).
observed_quantile_covs <- cov(t(repeated_quantiles))

cov_numerators <- outer(
  cum_probs,
  cum_probs,
  function(pi, pj) {pmin(pi, pj) * (1 - pmax(pi, pj))})
cov_denominators <- outer(
  z_scores,
  z_scores,
  function(zi, zj) {dnorm(zi) * dnorm(zj)})
theoretical_quantile_covs <- (true_sigma^2 / N) * cov_numerators / 
                                                  cov_denominators
attributes(theoretical_quantile_covs) <- attributes(observed_quantile_covs)

print(observed_quantile_covs)
#>              3%         10%         50%         90%         97%
#> 3%  0.062552746 0.022401688 0.005552923 0.002397237 0.002067152
#> 10% 0.022401688 0.029040887 0.007204680 0.003160199 0.002341112
#> 50% 0.005552923 0.007204680 0.015672809 0.007117486 0.005371020
#> 90% 0.002397237 0.003160199 0.007117486 0.029416612 0.022653584
#> 97% 0.002067152 0.002341112 0.005371020 0.022653584 0.062689044

print(theoretical_quantile_covs)
#>             3%         10%         50%         90%         97%
#> 3%  0.062854947 0.022610700 0.005525918 0.002512300 0.001943967
#> 10% 0.022610700 0.029221098 0.007141459 0.003246789 0.002512300
#> 50% 0.005525918 0.007141459 0.015707963 0.007141459 0.005525918
#> 90% 0.002512300 0.003246789 0.007141459 0.029221098 0.022610700
#> 97% 0.001943967 0.002512300 0.005525918 0.022610700 0.062854947

Note the variances that reappear along the diagonal. The covariances are quite large too, so we'll take care to account for them in our weighting. Our weights matrix $\mathbf{W}$ is the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix, after ignoring the $\sigma^2/N$ factor.
estimate_params_using_weights <- function(
    percentiles,
    cum_probs = c(0.03, 0.10, 0.50, 0.90, 0.97)) {
  z_scores <- qnorm(cum_probs)
  cov_numerators <- outer(
    cum_probs,
    cum_probs, 
    function(pi, pj) {pmin(pi, pj) * (1 - pmax(pi, pj))})
  cov_denominators <- outer(
    z_scores,
    z_scores,
    function(zi, zj) {dnorm(zi) * dnorm(zj)})
  W <- solve(cov_numerators / cov_denominators)
  # lm in base R doesn't accept matrix of weights but lm.gls in MASS does
  model <- MASS::lm.gls(percentiles ~ z_scores, W = W)
  params <- coefficients(model)
  names(params) <- c("mu", "sigma")
  return(params)
}

What difference does this weighting make to our parameter estimates?
# Estimate parameters from the quantiles we repeatedly sampled before
param_estimates_without_weights <- apply(
  repeated_quantiles,
  2, # means we apply to each column 
  estimate_params)
print(param_estimates_without_weights[, 1:7])
#>        sample 1  sample 2 sample 3  sample 4 sample 5 sample 6 sample 7
#> mu    42.015122 41.869716 41.93647 41.973855 42.19523 41.81662 41.80382
#> sigma  9.936526  9.986012 10.05289  9.869981 10.00277 10.02124  9.99102

param_estimates_with_weights <- apply(
  repeated_quantiles,
  2,
  estimate_params_using_weights)
print(param_estimates_with_weights[, 1:7])
#>        sample 1  sample 2 sample 3 sample 4 sample 5  sample 6 sample 7
#> mu    42.049797 41.896277 41.91803 41.94067 42.12420 41.906792 41.81145
#> sigma  9.890345  9.964559 10.07830  9.89824 10.00167  9.999696 10.0189

Looking at the first 7 sets of parameter estimates, it wasn't obvious that applying weights was very beneficial: in the very first sample it makes both $\hat \mu$ and $\hat \sigma$ estimates  worse! Nevertheless, we would be better to judge across all 100,000 samples.
# Density plot of mu estimates
mu_estimate_density_without_weights <- density(param_estimates_without_weights[1, ]) 
mu_estimate_density_with_weights <- density(param_estimates_with_weights[1, ]) 
plot(mu_estimate_density_with_weights, col = "red", main = "Estimated mu")
lines(mu_estimate_density_without_weights, col = "blue")
legend(x = "topleft",
       legend = c("weighted", "unweighted"),
       col = c("red", "blue"),
       lty = 1)


# Check the variance of our estimators
apply(
  param_estimates_without_weights,
  1, # applying variance over the rows
  var)
#>          mu       sigma 
#> 0.014396250 0.006600722 

apply(
  param_estimates_with_weights,
  1,
  var)
#>          mu       sigma 
#> 0.011233966 0.006202921

So we do see a reduction in the variance of our estimates when we apply weighting, and the density plot shows a sharper peak around the true value.
As before, we can precompute the coefficients we want rather than running a fresh WLS regression on each new sample result. The difference between weighted and ordinary least-squares regression is the presence of the weights matrix $\mathbf{W}$ in the formula. Our vector of parameter estimates is given by  $(\mathbf{X}^t\mathbf{WX})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^t \mathbf{W}$ (which we precompute) multiplied by the vector of quantiles $\mathbf{q}$.
precompute_coefficients_using_weights <- function(cum_probs) {
  n <- length(cum_probs)
  z_scores <- qnorm(cum_probs)
  cov_numerators <- outer(cum_probs, cum_probs, 
                          function(pi, pj) {pmin(pi, pj) * (1 - pmax(pi, pj))})
  cov_denominators <- outer(z_scores, z_scores,
                            function(zi, zj) {dnorm(zi) * dnorm(zj)})
  W <- solve(cov_numerators / cov_denominators)
  X <- matrix(c(rep(1, n), z_scores), ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
  coefs <- solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% W
  rownames(coefs) <- c("mu", "sigma")
  colnames(coefs) <- names(quantile(0, cum_probs))
  coefs
}

our_coefs_with_weights <- precompute_coefficients_using_weights(cum_probs = cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(our_coefs_with_weights, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>       3%            10%           50%           90%          97%         
#> mu    "0.05615100"  "0.19294306"  "0.50181186"  "0.19294306" "0.05615100"
#> sigma "-0.12151258" "-0.21182129" "-0.00000000" "0.21182129" "0.12151258"

# check matrix multiplication gives same result as regression
our_coefs_with_weights %*% repeated_quantiles[, 1]
#>            [,1]
#> mu    42.049797
#> sigma  9.890345

We see the weighted coefficients dramatically de-emphasise the extreme percentiles.
\begin{align}
\hat \mu &= 0.50181186q_{0.5} + 0.19294306(q_{0.1} + q_{0.9}) + 0.05615100(q_{0.03} + q_{0.97}) \\
\hat \sigma &= 0.21182129(q_{0.97} - q_{0.03}) + 0.12151258(q_{0.9} - q_{0.1})
\end{align}

To help future readers wondering about other quantiles, you can use the above code but with cum_probs set to your desired cumulative probabilities, as below. It's instructive to try experimenting with different quantiles, and especially the effect of packing some quantiles close together like cum_probs = c(0.01, 0.49, 0.50, 0.51, 0.99) so the covariance structure really comes into play. In that example, the median is so tightly squeezed between the 49th and 51st percentiles that it is of little worth in parameter estimation. Our algorithm detects this via the strong correlation between the 49th, 50th and 51st percentiles. Why not try it, then see how well you can guess what happens if we just use cum_probs = c(0.01, 0.49, 0.51, 0.99) or cum_probs = c(0.01, 0.50, 0.99) instead?
How to use quartiles to estimate the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution
Using weighted least-squares to account for the variance and covariance of the quartiles turns out to make no difference at all to our estimated SD and very little difference to our estimated mean.
cum_probs <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)

quartile_coefs_without_weights <- precompute_coefficients(cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(quartile_coefs_without_weights, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>       25%           50%          75%         
#> mu    "0.33333333"  "0.33333333" "0.33333333"
#> sigma "-0.74130111" "0.00000000" "0.74130111"

quartile_coefs_with_weights <- precompute_coefficients_using_weights(cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(quartile_coefs_with_weights, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>      25%           50%           75%         
#> mu    "0.34949109"  "0.30101781"  "0.34949109"
#> sigma "-0.74130111" "-0.00000000" "0.74130111"

Across 100,000 samples, applying weights reduced the variance of $\hat \mu$ from 0.011643 to 0.011636, so made little improvement. The variance of $\hat \sigma$ was 0.013651 either way. Note that this is a lot worse (and the variance of the estimator for the mean is slightly worse) than when we had the 3rd, 10th, 50th, 90th and 97th percentiles available. With less information, we are making worse estimates, especially of the SD.
With weightings applied, the linear combinations of quartiles that give our mean and SD estimates are:
\begin{align}
\hat \mu &= 0.30101781 q_{0.5} + 0.34949109(q_{0.25} + q_{0.75}) \\
\hat \sigma &= 0.74130111(q_{0.75} - q_{0.25})
\end{align}
Note that $0.74130111 = (\Phi^{-1}(0.75) - \Phi^{-1}(0.25))^{-1}$ so the formula for $\hat \sigma$ is exactly what you'd get if you "naively" tried calculating $\hat \sigma$ from the upper and lower quartile only.
How to use deciles to estimate the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution
The least-squares estimators for mean and SD change slightly when we weight to account for the variance and covariance of the sample deciles. Interestingly, more weight is given to extreme deciles, despite their increased sampling variance. This seems to be a consequence of the covariance structure: information from the middling  deciles is somewhat redundant, as they are so correlated with each other, whereas the extreme deciles are mostly correlated only with the few that are out near them. In 100,000 repeated samples, I found the variance of the $\hat \mu$ estimate fell from 0.010447 to 0.010431 when weights were applied; variance of the $\hat \sigma$ estimate fell from 0.007199 to 0.007152.
cum_probs <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)

decile_coefs_without_weights <- precompute_coefficients(cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(decile_coefs_without_weights, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>       10%           20%           30%           40%           50%          
#> mu    "0.11111111"  "0.11111111"  "0.11111111"  "0.11111111"  "0.11111111" 
#> sigma "-0.23821712" "-0.15644207" "-0.09747651" "-0.04709262" "-0.00000000"
#>       #> 60%          70%          80%          90%         
#> mu    "0.11111111" "0.11111111" "0.11111111" "0.11111111"
#> sigma "0.04709262" "0.09747651" "0.15644207" "0.23821712"


decile_coefs_with_weights <- precompute_coefficients_using_weights(cum_probs)
# print to 8 decimal places
apply(decile_coefs_with_weights, 1:2, function(x) {sprintf("%.8f", x)})
#>       10%           20%           30%           40%           50%         
#> mu    "0.12998827"  "0.10722955"  "0.10542941"  "0.10494059"  "0.10482436"
#> sigma "-0.26754874" "-0.12753106" "-0.07710855" "-0.03692122" "0.00000000"
#>       60%          70%          80%          90%         
#> mu    "0.10494059" "0.10542941" "0.10722955" "0.12998827"
#> sigma "0.03692122" "0.07710855" "0.12753106" "0.26754874"

With weightings applied, the linear combinations of quartiles that give our mean and SD estimates are:
\begin{align}
\hat \mu &= 0.10482436 q_{0.5} + 0.10494059(q_{0.4} + q_{0.6}) + 0.10542941(q_{0.3} + q_{0.7}) + \\
     &  0.10722955(q_{0.2} + q_{0.8}) + 0.12998827(q_{0.1} + q_{0.9}) \\
\hat \sigma &= 0.03692122(q_{0.6} - q_{0.4}) + 0.07710855(q_{0.7} - q_{0.3}) + \\
& 0.12753106(q_{0.8} - q_{0.2}) + 0.26754874(q_{0.9} - q_{0.1})
\end{align}

This is lovely detail.  It's beyond what I'm looking to do, but I want to signal my appreciation for it.

@Omroth The estimated parameters from a least-squares regression (either ordinary or weighted) are just a linear combination of the observed data. If you always use the same percentiles, neither your design matrix nor weights are going to change from sample to sample. So the coefficients for the linear combination you need are going to stay the same, and we can precompute them! This means you don't need to do a regression each time you get a new sample. Instead you can just use a very simple formula for your application, which I've added to my answer.

Aha, that addition is indeed something I can put in!  Thanks again

@Omroth I now updated the precomputed coefficients so they make use of the full covariance matrix of the sample quantiles. You can see this puts a lot of emphasis on the median: just over a 50% contribution to our estimated mean!
